# uninitialized constant Cloudinary::UploadedFile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I am using Cloudinary with rails and Devise.

when I create a new user I have a before_save filter that execute this

```
 if !self.image.blank?
      preloader = Cloudinary::UploadedFile.new(self.image)
      if preloader && preloader.valid?
        self.image = preloader.identifier
      end
end
```

and I obtain this error

```
uninitialized constant Cloudinary::UploadedFile
```

any idea

Comment: I don't think that the class `UploadedFile` exists. Do you mean `Uploader.upload`?

Comment: It's been over a month since you've posted this question. Have you had any luck with any of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Cloudinary may not yet be loaded into your Rails environment. First, try restarting your server.

Then, it looks like the class `UploadedFile` appears **[nowhere in the codebase](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/search?q=UploadedFile&type=Code)**. From the [docs](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration), it looks like what you're looking for is the `Upload` class – something akin to this:

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload('http://www.example.com/image.jpg')
```